# My dishwasher keeps jamming, it's not draining water, has sitting water in the bottom

Tags: dishwasher, clog

Not sure if this is my dishwasher or my clogged drains. A few years back, my dishwasher stopped draining; I called my neighbor, I tried all home remedies, my neighbor took the Bosch dishwasher apart and the hose inside was full of grease, so much that there was no way we could clean it. I ordered another one and replaced it. Still the water wasn't draining.
He climbed my roof, looked thru the drain pipe and said he sees clogged drain, hair and stuff, cleared that out and everything was good for good 2 years I would say.

Now, I have the same issue again. My neighbor has moved.
I'm not sure why this is happening. Should I call a plumber or a dishwasher person?

I'm afraid of termites due to standing water. This is Long Island, New York. Termites are a big issue. What should I do?

Comment: Termites inside the dishwasher? I have never heard that one. It is possible the drain is plugged again a plumber would be a better prepared to clean the pipes than a service tech for a dishwasher.

Comment: Probably "the hose inside was full of grease" again. Call whoever will come to your house for the cheapest rate and (pay them after they) fix it *after you tell them* your DW has a grease plug in it. Either or, or just a plan old handyman.

Comment: Do you clean your plates under the tap before placing in dishwasher to sanitize them? If not, then you know why it is clogged.

Comment: Did water from the sink drain at all when it first clogged?  Yeah you shouldn't have to worry about water sitting there, termites like "wet wood" and I presume your dishwasher isn't actually leaking any water onto the floor...? :)

Answer (score 1):

First, check and clean the drain filter in your dishwasher. This is a screen that can be pulled out from inside the dishwasher, designed to prevent food particles from getting sucked into the washing and drainage systems. Consult your manual for detailed instructions. This is something everyone should do regularly (every few months or more) to keep their dishwasher working well.

If that doesn't help, call a plumber. These issues can compound each other. If your drain line is clogged, your dishwasher will be struggling to run its drain pump. This will wear the pump out sooner, and the slow drainage will mean that any dirt that might flow out the drain will be more likely to cling to the walls of the drainage hose.

You should also look at how your dishwasher drain is connected. Usually it is attached to the same drain as your kitchen sink. Try filling up your sink with a stopper, then pull the stopper and see if it drains fast. If that is slow, then you most likely have a drain or venting issue which would affect the dishwasher as well. A plumber can fix that for you too.

The only reason you'd need a dishwasher tech is if the drain pump in the dishwasher needs to be replaced. That is a possibility, but less likely than the others. If that does turn out to be the issue, then plumber should at least be able to figure it out definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick that will keep your drain hose, drain, and dishwasher free of repeated blockage. Place a coffee cup upright in the back of your dishwasher lower rack, Fill it full of white vinegar and leave it there for two weeks and then refill it and repeat. As the vinegar releases it cleans everything. Also check to see if you use too much soap most dishwashers only use about two gallons of water per cycle. If oversudsing occurs soap builds up